# Crate exploit in Spelunky HTML5

Tags: spelunky-html5

I've recently been playing Spelunky HTML5, on a chromebook downloaded from the chrome web store. I've heard that there is an exploit that allows you to open up an item crate an infinite amount of times. Apparently it involves starting near a crate, and will not work if you jump or collect any money. I haven't been able to do this exploit, can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a general population of people seem to be able to replicate the bug doing the same thing, the bug itself is to do with only being able to jump half a block high.

To replicate it you have to not jump and not pickup gold, When you spawn near a box you simply walk up to it and press up+x this should then give you items and you should be able to keep using up+x to loot.

Hope this helps.

Edit: if you do pickup gold or jump you may have to restart your game, equally if you dont spawn near a crate you will need to restart.

Answer (score -8):

It is really hard to do, but you have to start near a crate. You cannot jump or collect gold. If you're lucky, it will work.

Comment: Any additional clarification?